# azure resource template: Can I assign complex variable to property?

Tags: templates, azure, resources, azure-resource-manager

I'm creating an Azure Resource Template and I'd like to assign the same set of tags to all my resources.  I can create a variable to hold all my tag values like this:

> ```
> "variables": {
>   "mytags": {
>     "project": "XyzProject",
>     "department": "AbcDept",
>     "owner": "Tom"
>   }
> }
> ```

And I can assign all the tags values individually like

> ```
> "tags": {
>   "project": "[variables('mytags').project]"
>   "department": "[variables('mytags').department]"
>   "owner": "[variables('mytags').owner]"
> }
> ```

but (a) I have to repeat this for every resource and (b) if I add a new name-value pair to the tags I have to modify the tags element in every resource.

Is it possible to assign the whole of "mytags" at once?

Something like

> "tags": variables('mytags')

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible in AzureRM right now, but it should be... we'll get a bug filed on it.